# iOS Simulator AND iOS Device showing black screen after running app

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, swift3, xcode8

I'm having a weird situation here, my simulator and my device show a black screen running the app. However, I do know that the storyboard is imported because the background music I added for the view controller is working, why is my view controller display not loading? It won't work for ANY view controller if I add one in the Storyboard file. Help?

Comment: Did you check the `initialViewController` property when dragging those view controllers to the storyboard?  Have no initial controller would cause your app to launch and show a black screen.

Comment: Yes, that has been checked. Which is why the music for the view is playing but for some reason the view won't display.

Comment: can you upload your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a new project copying everything to it and it works.